# javascript - function with setInterval not starting immediately on page load

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this code that continuously accesses a url at given intervals:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var valr5 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = valr5.wind;
        }
    };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "sample.com/", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }, 30000);}
```

My problem is that the script would run after 30s, as set in the code. So the page is blank for 30s.

What I want to happen is on page load, the script will run so I won't see I blank page, and from that, access the URL every 30s or so.

How can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the function in a variable first, call the function, then call `setInterval` with it:

```
const updateWind = () => {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var valr5 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("wind").innerHTML = valr5.wind;
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "sample.com/", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
updateWind();
window.setInterval(updateWind, 30000);
```